# how to viewing VPN Parameters on Google Cloud - Phase 1 and Phase?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, encryption, vpn, google-cloud-vpn

I've got a classic VPN set up on Google Cloud, and it's been working great. But now I've got a burning question: How can I check out my VPN's parameters? Specifically, I'd like to take a peek at the Phase 1 and Phase 2 settings. The four parameters I'm interested in are:

Diffie Hellman
Hashing
Encryption Type
Lifetime

If anyone has a clue on how to access this info or if there's some magic command I can use in Google Cloud to uncover these secrets, please spill the beans! I really appreciate any help you can offer. Thanks in advance!